# User permissions for BizTalk server

Tags: permissions, biztalk

I've got my dev machine with BizTalk running as local administrator, and I get the warning that it should be ... but I still do

But what's the best security group to put the BizTalk user in on a "live" server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BizTalk Application Users.

Check the [BizTalk 2006 R2 installation guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=df2e8a88-fb23-49a4-9ac7-d17f72517d12&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 3):

I second Rodrigo's recommendation of looking at the installation guide. However, I'll also add that in most live environments you'll want to do a good security planning before installing, as a secure and functional deployment can be complex.

In particular, play close attention to the permissions required by each person interacting with BizTalk (sysadmins, sql admins, etc) and make sure you define separate accounts for each service / host and how they should be configured.

Normally, you'll deploy BizTalk with at least two separate machines (one running SQL server for the databases and one running BizTalk itself). This requires that you define your BizTalk accounts and security groups before hand and that you create them in your AD infrastructure *before* deployment, so make sure you get that right.

Even if you're going to deploy everything to a single server, make sure you use domain accounts for everything and don't skip the security planning. This will make it a *lot* easier to later move to a multi-server deployment without having to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an IT admin 50% of the time. And a developer the other 50%.  It's your dev machine. Off course you should run everything as an admin. Never mind the warning. You know what you are doing right? If not .. read up on access rights as linked to in Rodrigo's answer. It is the next level - the common dev/test machine where you should meet the problems of running under realistic conditions....

This is a common dev/IT ops question and not just related to BizTalk. I know this is an old answer but I hope dev's are picking up what I'm putting down....